# Update query executed successfully but data is not updated

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

i am working on a project in which i have use the Update Query but the problem is that after the query is executed successfully the data is not updated
here is my code

```
protected void Update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var aid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Aid"].ToString());
    try
    {
        var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "Update Tasks set TaskName=@tname,TaskDetails=@tdetails WHERE Id=@id and CreatedBy=@aid";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", taskname_tb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdetails", Detail_ta.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Convert.ToInt32(id_tb.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid",aid);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.RedirectPermanent("~/AllTasks.aspx",false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>Some Error occured</script>");
    }
}
```

tried the parameters without converting to `int32`
but same results
also when run the query in sql it works fine.

**Schema of Table Tasks**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks] (
[Id]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TaskName]     VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
[TaskDetails]  VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[CreationDate] DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy]    INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_ToAccounts] FOREIGN KEY ([CreatedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([Id])
```

);

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I didn't know about issues with AddWithValue.  That's good to know.  But just in case... any triggers on the table?  I always blame triggers when odd behavior like this happens.

Comment: @marc_s not even work like that `cmd.Parameters.Add("@tname",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = taskname_tb.Text;`

Comment: @RThomas no triggers binded

Comment: You've stepped through it? You absolutely know for sure this code block gets hit?  Specifically cmd.ExecuteNonQuery.  ---  You could also run a trace on your SQL box and see when and where it hits as well as actual TSQL syntax passed for verification.

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string**? Are you using an "attached" `.mdf` file ?

Comment: @marc_s `<add name="AccountsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Smartlyfe(DB).mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Most likely, your `UPDATE` is just fine - it's just updating the **wrong** database. When you run this in Visual Studio, I bet the `.mdf` file is copied to the `.\bin\debug` folder, and updated **there** - so if you check your file in `App_Data`, you won't see the update. Two solutions: **(1)** use a **fully-qualified path name** (`c:\something\app_data\smartlyfe.mdf` or **(2)** put your database **on the server** and reference it using a logical database name and stop fiddling around with free-floating files altogether.

Comment: Also see: [Working with local database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx) on MSDN that explains a bit more how `.mdf` files are copied around - and how to solve it

Comment: @marc_s no db file `\bin\debug` and `Fully-qualified path name` is also not working

Comment: Even moving the db to server also not works

Comment: And are you **1000%** sure that you **do have** rows that match the `WHERE` criteria of your `UPDATE` statement??? If you get the number of rows affected:  `int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - what number do you get??

Comment: @marc_s `int value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` return 1
it means that table name is correct db name is correct column names are correct

Comment: Yes, but updating zero rows is still a successful update. This is why marc_s asks how many rows get affected.

Answer (score 0):

First try running following query

select * from  Tasks WHERE Id=@id and CreatedBy=@aid

it should return one row.

Second try to rename your database file when your application is running. Since you have not manually disposed your connection so if you try to rename/delete database file system should not allow it.

Comment: Yup the above query is returning a record and secondly it is not allowing to rename DB while Application is runing

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**
after thinking alot on the above problem i found that
i have not added `Is.Postback` in `Page_Load()` so when i click update button the page `Asp.Net` **page life cycle** occurs and it again fetches old value and update it so i am unable to see any changes coz it is updating old data

Comment: It seems at no time did you ever actually check the actual database value